# Is this rook endgame won for white?

Tags: analysis, theory, endgame, rook-endgame

In *Dvoretsky's Endgame Manual, 2nd Edition* from 2006 the following important practical rook endgame with a distant passed pawn is analysed. The whole analysis (of the same position with white to move and black to move) is on pages 194-200.

```
 [Title "White to move"] 
 [SetUp "1"]
 [FEN "8/R4p2/P4kp1/7p/7P/4K1P1/r4P2/8 w - - 0 1"]

 1.Kd4! Rxf2 2. Rc7 Ra2 3. a7 Kf5 4. Kc4!! {Johannes Steckner} Kg4 5. Kb3! Ra6 6. Rc4+ Kxg3 7. Ra4 Rxa7 8. Rxa7 Kxh4 9. Kc3 Kg3 10. Kd2 h4 11. Ke2 Kg2 12. Rxf7 h3 13. Rf2+! Kg3 14. Rf6 +-
```

The author claims, with very long analyses to back it up, that white wins after `Kd4!`, but he warns:

> Nothing could be further from my mind than to label the analyses presented [...] as the "last word of theory" - long, complicated variations rarely turn out error-free.

Have there been any new developments since 2006?

I know 11-men tablebases are a long way off, but are we still confident this endgame is a win for white?

Comment: +1 Good endgame to analyze over the coming long weekend!

Comment: Bonus question: Can black make a draw if it's their move? Dvoretsky thinks so.

Comment: The whole analysis (white to move and black to move) is on pages 194-200. The text is quite dense with a two-column format. It's too much to copy everything, but I can give some main lines.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen, I found it odd that Dvoretsky considers only 1...Rxf2 for Black after 1. Kd4! You know what move I'm hinting at!

Comment: I don't know what move you are thinking of, but `1. Kd4 g5` is quite thematic to break up the pawn structure and try to create a passed pawn as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, Dvoretsky has completely ignored that line.

Comment: I plugged the initial position into FinalGen, after 11 hours and 400 GB, it claims there is still 20 hours remaining to generate all the positions. Maybe someone else has tried that on a faster PC?

Comment: This looks like a "textbook" ending that White can win with "best play." That is not to say that I can win it (unless my opponent is weaker than me).

Comment: For the purpose of Google searches, could you edit your question to include the page numbers where this endgame is found in the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entire endgame has been analyzed thoroughly on [ChessPub](http://www.chesspub.com/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1320323463/21). It seems that member *Wes* was right -> `...g5` is the main move. This was confirmed with a lengthy analysis at [ChessCafe](http://www.chesscafe.com/text/mueller132.pdf) -> see the first position on the page ( there are some other games analyzed after the analysis of this position finishes ). I am sorry for posting links but the analysis is huge!

Good luck and hopefully this answered your question!

Best regards!

Comment: My suggestion was 1. Kd4 g5! and not playing g5 after first taking on f2. Don't take on f2 at all. Just play 1...g5! I think that's the critical line. The book does a fine job of refuting 1...Rxf2 already.

Comment: @Wes: Your "gut feeling" was good, it is the only move that leads to a draw! See detailed analysis in links I posted ( I have edited my answer ). Well done! Best regards.

Comment: It's amazing what possibilities exist in such a simple position.

Comment: Thank you for officially accepting, I hope you learned a lot as I have. What an amazing piece of art can be contained in such a simple endgame! Best regards.

Comment: The ChessCafe analysis is now behind a paywall. Is it possible to make a short summary?

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen I will try to do something during weekend (it has been roughly 4 years since my last time here, I need to refresh my memory aboud Chess SE diagrams and such stuff...).